# Use same DataAdapter object for multiple queries causing RaceOnRCWCleanup

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an application which does quite a few database queries. In order to speed up the application I do some queries which are independent of each other (it doesn't matter which order they get updated in as they aren't referencing one another) on a separate thread.

However, it *appears* that if two queries are executed at the same time on the different threads, but one finishes earlier, the DataAdapter attempts to close the connection which is still being used on another thread resulting in a RaceOnRCWCleanup warning:

`An attempt has been made to free an RCW that is in use.  The RCW is in use on the active thread or another thread.  Attempting to free an in-use RCW can cause corruption or data loss.`

I may be incorrect about this assumption but if I don't call any queries on the secondary thread, or delay them, I don't seem to get this issue. If I force the queries to happen at the same time, I get the warning.

My query functions are, with a few exceptions, all structured as such:

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT..."

Try
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
    da.Fill(dsData, "Progress")

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try

Return dsData.Tables("Progress")
```

And da is declared in a separate module as:

`Public da As OleDbDataAdapter`

I thought by declaring `da = New` I force it to be a new object and therefore, closing the connection on one should not effect the other?

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved this by using a separate `OleDbConnection` object for each thread (I never call the same functions across different threads).

This way a single connection object is only ever used in serial.

I don't know if this is the correct way to handle this but it seems to work.